# Formatting bytes array

Tags: c, winapi

i use the function readfile() to get some bytes from a prefetch file

```
BYTE   ReadBuffer[24];

for(i=0; i < 24; (i++))
{
  printf("%02X", *(ReadBuffer+i));
}
```

if i use %02X i get same result as my hex editor:

```
43 00 4F 00 4E 00 48 00 4F 00 53 00 54 00 2E 00 45 00 58 00 45 00 00 00
```

if i use %C :

```
C O N H O S T . E X E
```

it's seems to be UTF-16LE, and 
i want as result CONHOST.exe (without space...) using WINAPI only

i try to use WideCharToMultiByte but it's not working..

```
CHAR AnsiPath[MAX_PATH]
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, (PWCHAR)Buffer, -1, AnsiPath, sizeof(AnsiPath), NULL, NULL)
```

someone can explain me where i fail ? thanks

here the full code

```
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD  dwBytesRead = 0;
    BYTE   ReadBuffer[10266];
    DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead = 10266;

    LPCWSTR fname = L"C:\\Windows\\Prefetch\\CONHOST.EXE-3218E401.pf";
    hFile = CreateFile(fname,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);


    if (!ReadFile(hFile, ReadBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    {
            printf("Terminal failure: Unable to read from file.\n GetLastError=%08x\n", GetLastError());
            CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    printf("Data read from %s (%d bytes): \n", fname, dwBytesRead);
    wprintf(L"%ld\n", ReadBuffer);
    int i;
    for(i=16; i < 40; i++)
    {
        printf("%C ", *(ReadBuffer+i));
    }
    char AnsiPath[MAX_PATH];
    int result = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (PWCHAR)ReadBuffer, -1, AnsiPath, 0,0,0);
    printf("\nResult WideCharToMultiByte : %d\n", result); 

    printf("\nString : %s \n",AnsiPath);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

the result :

```
Data read from C (9068 bytes):
3199640
C   O   N   H   O   S   T   .   E   X   E
Result WideCharToMultiByte : 2

String : ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠(
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

Comment: "It's not working". I can assure you that `WideCharToMultiByte` works fine. Your code is not working. Please describe how it fails. I note also that you are failing to check the return value of `WideCharToMultiByte`. That is always a mistake.

Comment: you right, i forget to say that WideCharToMultiByte return me 2.. i think that is not the correct size

Comment: What does that cast do? Do you need to cast it like this: `(PWCHAR)&ReadBuffer`? I don't know what `Buffer` is. It only appears in the call to `WideCharToMultiByte`. If only you'd provided a full program we wouldn't have to go through this painful process.

Comment: if you look closely on your data, you'll see many of alternating zeros. so you may simple outputting significant characters: `... if (i % 2 == 0) printf ("%C", ...);`

Comment: @EDkan No please. You don't convert unicode by removing zeros.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me as is, if I replace `Buffer` by `ReadBuffer`.

Comment: i did that EDkan but its not clean :(
i edited by post with the full code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the new code you posted :

It looks like your string start at the 16th byte of the `ReadBuffer`, therefore your need to convert from that, using `ReadBuffer+16` or whatever.

You forgot the `sizeof(AnsiPath)`, like in the lines you posted just above.

Comment: omg 2days that i search.. it's working.. i was using the FULL ReadBuffer not the bytes 16 to 40...:-/ thanks you !! :)